# Can use a wrappanel with datatemplate for horizontal alignment of items in a listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to horizontally align items in a listbox(items are checkbox items). How can i use a wrap panel with datatemplate?

```
<ListBox  Name="Horizontal"  ItemsSource="{Binding Solution}" scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate >
 <DataTemplate >
  <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="5 5 0 0"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Put WrapPanel inside ListBox.ItemsPanel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want the `ItemsPanel` property:

```
<ListBox Name="Horizontal" ItemsSource="{Binding Solution}" scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="5 5 0 0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```